# Why gets does not work when I use it with scanf?

Tags: c

When i use **gets** separately this works. But, when i use **scanf** in my program it does not work. Can anyone explain what I've missed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char a[]="computer";
    char b[]={'p','c','\0'};
    char c[30];
    char d[30];
    printf("a=%s,b=%s\n",a,b);
    printf("enter a word\n");
    scanf("%s",c);
    printf("%s",c);
    printf("enter a sentence\n");
    gets (d);
    printf("%s",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use `gets`. It is inherently unsafe, and has been removed from the language as of the 2011 ISO C standard. You can use `fgets` instead (though it's slightly more complicated to use).

Comment: A more productive comment would also suggest an alternative, @KeithThompson.

Comment: so how can i enter a two part word(for example computer science) and print it?scanf just print(computer).

Comment: I think that the "`scanf()` leaves a newline in the stream" problem  has now become the most frequently asked C question on SO, surpassing problems comparing floating point values for equality and what `i++ - ++i` evaluates to.

Comment: @Michael Burr How about why doesn't `char i; float fp; scanf("%f", &fp); i = (scanf("%c", &i) - i++) * fp / 10 == 0.1 * ++i; }` work? :-)

Comment: What is `gets`. I think you forget the f it should be `fgets`

Comment: no,we have **gets ();** and it works when we dont use scanf. try my code without scanf.

Comment: @chux wins Stackoverflow for the day. Please use it for good, not evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`gets` doesn't skip the white-space characters before starting to read the string while `scanf` does**.
After your first input, there is `\n` character in the buffer left behind by first `scanf` call. This `\n` is read by `gets` but `scanf` skips this white-space character.
this can be solved by using a `getchar` statement after the `scanf` call.

```
printf("enter a word\n");
scanf("%s",c);
getchar();
```

Do not use `gets` neither `scanf` (they do not check array bound), instead use `fgets`.

```
printf("enter a word\n");
fgets(c, 30, stdin);
printf("%s",c);
printf("enter a sentence\n");
fgets(d, 30, stdin);
printf("%s",d);
```

Comment: Consider re-wording about `scanf()` skipping whitespace.  `scanf()` does not always skip whitespace - it depends on the format string.

Comment: @haccks;**fgets();** and **gets ();** both work when we don't have scanf,and non of them work when we have scanf,so what is the difference now?

Comment: `gets` is not safe to use. It does't stop the input to write beyond the allocated memory. `fgets`'s second parameter is used for that purpose and it is safe. But keep in mind that both will read `\n`. @chux; `scanf` does skip white-spaces before starting to read ***string***.

Comment: @haccks Using `scanf()` a _string_ may be read either using the `"%s"` format specifier, which does skip leading whitespace and `"%[]"` which does not.

Answer (score 1):

Scanf leaves behind "\n"(without quotes) and then gets() function reads only it.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s",c)` left the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `\n` in `stdin`.  When `gets()` executed it consumed that and returned an empty string.  `gets()` reads in all data up to the `\n` and trims it off before returning.

The format specifiers like `%d %s`, etc. (all except `%n %c %[`) and the whitespace format directives like `" "` direct `scanf()` to skip leading whitespace.  `scanf()` itself does not skip leading whitespace.

Suggest using `fgets()` and avoid using `gets()`.

```
char buf[100];
printf("enter a word\n");
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
sscanf(buf, "%29s", c);  // 29 because c is size 30
printf("%s\n",c);

printf("enter a sentence\n");
fgets(d, sizeof d, stdin);
printf("%s",d);
```

Comment: @s12b11 Try typing in a 50 letter _sentence_  like "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij" and see the difference between `gets()` and `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` removes whitespace automatically from *before* the datum it's trying to get. An exception to this is the character formats (primarily `%c`), which don't remove whitespace. However, `scanf` leaves whitespace *after* the datum. Therefore, you'll need a way to get rid of that. Use

```
getc(stdin);
```

you can then continue on your merry way. [This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/) has more documentation on `getc`.

Comment: How **getc(stdin);** works?would be grateful if you show it with a code.

Comment: @s12b11, that is the code for using `getc`. I've added a link to a documentation page.